# Prove mean and variance of $\overline{X}$.

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, variance, sampling

> If a random sample of size $n$ is selected without replacement from
> the finite population that consists of the integers $1, 2, \ldots ,N$,
> show that
>
> a. $E(\overline{X})=\dfrac{N+1}{2}$.
>
> b. $var(\overline{X})=\dfrac{(N+1)(N-n)}{12n}$.

To answer this question, I construct the p.d.f of discrete random variable $X$ which have uniform distribution, i.e.

\begin{align}
p_X(x)=\dfrac{1}{N},  x=1,2,\ldots,N.
\end{align}
Now I find the mean of $X$, i.e.
$$E(X)=\sum\limits_{x=1}^N xp_X(x)=\dfrac{1}{N}(1+2+\ldots+N)=\dfrac{1}{N}\dfrac{N(N+1)}{2}=\dfrac{N+1}{2}.$$
The second moment of $X$ is
\begin{align}
E(X^2)=\sum\limits_{x=1}^N x^2 p_X(x)=\dfrac{1}{N}(1^2+2^2+\ldots+N^2)=\dfrac{1}{N}\dfrac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}=\dfrac{(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}.
\end{align}
So, the variance of $X$ is
\begin{align}
var(X)&=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2\\
&=\dfrac{(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}-\dfrac{(N+1)^2}{4}\\
&=(N+1)\left(\dfrac{2N+1}{6}-\dfrac{N+1}{4}\right)\\
&=(N+1)\left(\dfrac{4N+2}{12}-\dfrac{3N+3}{12}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{(N+1)(N-1)}{12}.
\end{align}

Now, I find the expectation and variance of $\overline{X}$ as follows.

\begin{align}
E(\overline{X})&=E\left(\dfrac{X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_n}{n}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{n}E(X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_n)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{n}(E(X_1)+E(X_2)+\ldots+E(X_n))\\
&=\dfrac{1}{n}(nE(X))\text{ (random samples are i.i.d.)}\\
&= E(X)\\
&=\dfrac{N+1}{2}.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
var(\overline{X})&=var\left(\dfrac{X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_n}{n}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{n^2}(var(X_1)+var(X_2)+\ldots+var(X_n))\\
&=\dfrac{1}{n^2}(n\cdot var(X))\\
&=\dfrac{var(X)}{n}\\
&=\dfrac{(N+1)(N-1)}{12n}.
\end{align}

I can prove $E(\overline{X})=\dfrac{N+1}{2}$. But I find
$$var(\overline{X})=\dfrac{(N+1)(N-1)}{12n},$$
not
$$var(\overline{X})=\dfrac{(N+1)(N-n)}{12n}.$$
What my mistake in my answer?

Comment: The random variables $X_i$ are ***not*** identically distributed, because the draws are ***without*** replacement.

Comment: The random variables $X_i$ are not independent, so that the variance of the sum $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ does not equal the sum of variances.

Comment: @Joe The random variables $X_i$ are identically distributed (but are not independent).

Comment: To find the variance of the sum you should go for:$$\mathsf{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)=\mathsf{Cov}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i,\sum_{j=1}^nX_j\right)$$ and make use of bilinearity of $\mathsf{Cov}$.

Comment: @drhab, that makes sense. I guess I was thinking of them as being drawn in sequence, and was thinking that the conditional distribution $P_{X_2|X_1}(x)$ isn't uniform over $1,\dots,N$, since $X_2\ne X_1$. But as you said, that's because they're not independent, so $P_{X_2}(x)\ne P_{X_2|X_1}(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$var\left(\frac{X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_n}{n}\right)\not=\dfrac{1}{n^2}(var(X_1)+var(X_2)+\ldots+var(X_n))$ due to the lack of independence

Instead use $E\left[\left(\frac{X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_n}{n}\right)^2\right] -\left(E\left[\frac{X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_n}{n}\right]\right)^2 = \frac1nE[X_i^2] + \frac{n-1}{n}E[X_iX_j] -(E[X_i])^2$ where $i\not = j$.  This is $$\frac1n\frac{(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}+\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{(N+1)(3N+2)}{12}-\frac{(N+1)^2}{4} = \frac{(N+1)(N-n)}{12n}$$